# SQL/PHP How to total the number in a row from the same time each day

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to figure out how to total the number of 'entries - exits' each hour of the day at the same time each week. ie How many entries-exits at 12.00pm each Tuesday, 1.00pm each Tuesday.

```
${'request'.'$i'} = "SELECT starttime AS time, SUM(enters-exits) as
  entries FROM DEV_DoorCam WHERE (CAST( starttime AS date )='$startDate' 
  AND CAST( starttime AS time )>='07:00:00' AND (zone_name='Entrance' OR
  zone_name='SideDoor')) GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime)) DIV 
  '".(int)$divisor."';";
try{    
    ${'result'.'$i'} = mysqli_query($conn, ${'request'.'$i'});
....
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(${'result'.'$i'})) {
        ${"DataSet".$i}[$row["time"]] = $row["entries"];
....
foreach(${"DataSet".$i} as $time => $entries){
        file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $time, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents('mydata.txt', "   ", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $entries, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents('mydata.txt', "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

This gives me the following

```
2016-06-17 07:00:00   8  //between 7 and 8 there are 8 more entries than exits
2016-06-17 08:00:00   8
2016-06-17 09:00:00   14
2016-06-17 10:00:00   2
2016-06-17 11:00:00   6
2016-06-17 12:00:00   0
2016-06-17 13:00:00   12
2016-06-17 14:00:00   9
2016-06-17 15:00:00   7
2016-06-17 16:00:00   -2
2016-06-17 17:00:00   0
2016-06-17 18:00:00   -9
2016-06-17 19:00:00   -2
2016-06-17 20:00:00   -5
2016-06-17 21:00:00   0
2016-06-17 22:00:00   0
2016-06-17 23:00:00   0

2016-06-18 07:00:00   7
2016-06-18 08:00:00   3
2016-06-18 09:00:00   11
2016-06-18 10:00:00   6
2016-06-18 11:00:00   8
2016-06-18 12:00:00   4
2016-06-18 13:00:00   -12
2016-06-18 14:00:00   5
2016-06-18 15:00:00   -7
....
....
```

How can I group them to total the 7.00 to 8.00 each Tuesday

Using (Ta Parfait)

```
SELECT DAYNAME(starttime) AS DayOfWeek, TIME(starttime) As TimeOfDay, 
SUM(enters-exits) as entries FROM DEV_DoorCam WHERE 
DAYOFWEEK(starttime)=1 AND TIME(starttime) >= '07:00:00' AND 
(zone_name='Entrance' OR zone_name='SideDoor') GROUP BY  
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime) DIV 3600) ORDER BY TIME(starttime);
```

I get

```
Sunday  07:00:00    21
Sunday  07:00:00    -2
Sunday  07:00:00    2
Sunday  08:00:00    3
Sunday  08:00:00    28
Sunday  08:00:00    -6
Sunday  09:00:00    0
Sunday  09:00:00    6
Sunday  09:00:00    15
```

What I want is

```
Sunday  07:00:00    21
Sunday  08:00:00    25
Sunday  09:00:00    21
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MySQL's [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html), particularly `DAYNAME()` and `TIME()` on `starttime` for groupings in the aggregate query:

```sql
SELECT DAYNAME(starttime) AS DayOfWeek, 
       TIME_FORMAT(TIME(starttime), '%H:00:00') As TimeOfDay, 
       SUM(enters-exits) as entries 
FROM DEV_DoorCam 
WHERE (TIME(starttime) >= '07:00:00') 
AND   (zone_name='Entrance' OR zone_name='SideDoor')
GROUP BY DAYNAME(starttime), 
         TIME_FORMAT(TIME(starttime), '%H:00:00')
```

And if you particularly only need Tuesdays, add to `WHERE` clause:

```sql
AND DAYNAME(starttime) = 'Tuesday'
```

OR

```sql
AND DAYOFWEEK(starttime) = 3
```

Comment: I changed the TIME(starttime) in your GROUP BY to (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime) DIV 3600), as in the DB there is an entry every 5 minutes so they have to be grouped to give an hours result. This doesn't add together the 'entries' for the same hour on the same day of the week. I want to get one figure for 'entries' at eg 7.00am on Thursdays (so four entries figures need to be grouped each month). (I'm not explaining myself very well, and it's so simple inside my noggin). Basically I want one figure for entries for a particular time each day.

Comment: See edit where you strip only the hour of the `starttime` and group by it.